# Tokenize by comma outside the brackets

Tags: regex, go

I'm desperately trying to tokenize a filter string which has following format:

```
price:gte:5.99,price:lte:10.00,model:in:[test1,test2]
```

The pitfall is that comma is used not only to separate filter options, but also as a separator for option lists: `[test1,test2]`

Applying standard regex tokenizer expression `[^,]+` gives me:

```
price:gte:5.99
price:lte:10.00
model:in:[test1
test2]
```

But, obviously, I want:

```
price:gte:5.99
price:lte:10.00
model:in:[test1,test2]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Regex101 playground link is [here](https://regex101.com/r/gvYA5N/1).

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: @anubhava Golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an option:

[`(?:[^][,\n]+\[[^]]+\]|[^,\n]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/RC9TCe/2)

**Explanation**

```
(?:                  # Non capturing group
  [^][,\n]+\[[^]]+\] # Match not a comma newline ] or [, then match between []
  |                  # Or
  [^,\n]+            # Match not a comma or a newline
)                    # Close non capturing group
```

**Edit:**
As suggested by @anubhava added `][` to the character class so that this becomes `[^][,\n]` to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark your answer as accepted since you were first with a working solution. Otherwise, @anubhava regex pattern works for me too.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: Please don't take this comment as offensive but just a minor correction my working edit was 8 seconds before this answer :) But of course it should be OP's prerogative to accept any answer.

Comment: @anubhava: I was expecting this kind of comment. What can I say? I really was hesitating, but unfortunately SO is not designed in such a way so I can accept both answers. I gave *The fourth bird* a preference for two reasons: he first posted a working solution, and at this moment he has 6.7k of reputation vs 472k yours. I'm not thinking that you have too much reputation, no. You totally earned it, and I highly respect that. But since I'm a huge SO fan, motivating people with small or average reputation is my personal prerogative.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: Totally respect your thought process. I wasn't questioning your selection at all.

Comment: Also if I may suggest, please use `(?:[^][,\n]+\[[^]]+\]|[^,\n]+)` in your code as `[^,]+` at the start will cause lot of backtracking in larger text.

Comment: @anubhava The comment about the backtracking was very valuable. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

golang regex doesn't support lookaheads assertion that makes this task bit more difficult.

You may use this regex using alternation:

```
[^][,]*(?:\[[^][]*\])+|[^,]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gvYA5N/5)

**Details:**

- `[^][,]+`: Match 1+ characters that are not `,` and `[` and `]`
- `(?:\[[^][]*\])+`: Match text between `[` or `]`. Match 1 or more of this group
- `|`: OR
- `[^,]+`: Match 1+ characters that are not comma

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for: `model:in:[test1,test2],price:gte:5.99,price:lte:10.00`